# Php decode soapenv:Envelope

Tags: php

how to I decode soap env on php. I have tried with

```
$your_xml_response =$data;
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $your_xml_response);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml)
```

but its not working. Is there other way?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:zuku">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:validate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <billNumber xsi:type="xsd:int" xs:type="type:int" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">798724</billNumber>
            <username xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">airtelug</username>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">TL2TVbXz3MhBh9JH</password>
        </urn:validate>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are not giving us enough information. Go back a few steps and show how you got here in your code,

Comment: Pretty sure PHP has Soap libraries, which ought to remove the need for manual XML parsing. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: Having just recently had to consume a SOAP API, I can't agree more with @ADyson. Look into a library for this, it is not worth the headache to write this by hand.

Comment: The prefix you tried to "clean" there is an XML namespace. The linked duplicate shows you how to process it. Using the SOAP classes *might* be an option, but they're not always as easy as they should be to get working (SOAP is a horribly bloated standard, and PHP's implementation is not very well documented or maintained).